# Не видит json файл через script, почему?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Вот так не работает

```
<head>
<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/test.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="model">
        <option  value="">Выберите </option>
    </select>
</body>
```

А вот так работает

```
<head>
<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="model">
        <option  value="">Выберите </option>
    </select>
//Он же содержимое TEST.js
<script>
$(function(){
    $.getJSON('model.json',function(data){
        $.each(data, function(key,val){
            $('#model').append('<option value="' + val + '">'+ key + '</option>');
        });
    });
});
</script>
</body>
```

Почему???

Model.json

```
{
  "Чехол": 1,
  "Коврик " : 2,
  "Комплект ": 3
}
```

Comment: добавьте в вопрос содержимое файла "js/test.js". Он загружается?

Comment: еще раз прошу добавить в Ваш вопрос **полное** содержимое файла "js/test.js". Он загружается? Проверьте это в "Development Tools" браузера.

Comment: @Igor Добавил...

Comment: где добавил? У Вас что, таг `<script>` в js файле?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нельзя подключать json таким образом.

Как вариант в test.js вы можете нписать что-то вроде:

```
var myJSON = { /* Ваши данные */};
```

и подключать как обычный javascript файл используя тег `<script>`

Comment: каким образом? ТС получает данные асинхронным запросом. Что в этом неправильно?

Comment: Как я понял `js/test.js` файл содержащий Json ... `<script src="js/test.js"></script>`

Comment: если не правильно понял, то код из `js/test.js`  в студию ...

Comment: @AlexeyLemesh Добавил